# Get sum of services from one cell

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am importing some data to sheets and need to sum the value of all the services.
This is the data format:

```
Service #6 ($250.00),  ServiceB ($150.00)
ServiceB ($40.00),  ServiceE ($150.00), ServiceE ($60.00)
Service 1 ($850.00), ServiceE  ($250.00), ServiceB ($450.00)
```

I just need to get the sum of all the values of the services in a new column. I was trying to get it via regexExtract but I only get the first value. The I was doing this with Split + regexExtrac but it's kind of messy because there isn't a limit to the number of services.

Can you guys think of any way to get the sum of all the service without the dollar sign to a column? I could write with AppScript but wanted to see if there is a simpler way?

Comment: Something like `=SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"[^$]*\$(\d+\.\d+)[^$]*","$1+"),"+",1,1))`

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this with AppScript:

```
function sumServices(input) {
  const sep = input.split(',');
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < sep.length; i++){
    var regExp = /\$(\d+)/g;
    let matches = sep[i].match(regExp);
    var regExp2 = /\d+/g;
    let final = matches[0].match(regExp2);
    let number = parseInt(final)
    sum = sum + number;
  }

  return(sum)
}
```